# Harmonica key advice sought

Tags: blues, harmonica

Could someone please clarify something for me... I'm a singer and far from being a harmonica player but I can bend a draw and find my way around.  A song that my band wants to play has a little bit of chugging harmonica over the intro.  The song is in D but we tune down half a step.  Would I be right in thinking I need an F#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're correct. Drawing on a harp gives the dominant chord notes of the harp key, so with an F# harp, you'll be drawing to make a C#9 chord.

F# harps aren't the most common. Might be time for the rest of the band to play the number in Eb concert, but I bet they won't be happy! But that puts you on a readily available G harp.

Comment: Thank you.  Getting guitarist to change keys is like getting them to turn it down... never going to happen :)  Thankfully, I have found an F# on ebay for a mere £7 (yes it will be crap but for 15 seconds out of a whole set, it'll do).

Comment: It's quite easy to get a guitarist to turn down the volume: you put some music in front of him...